# Inversion's Number On Mergesort Algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I have applied mergesort algorithm to an array in JAVA but I need to print the number of inversions realized.

I have drawed a diagram of how I think the inversions are count (I don't undestand it very well).

I counted 18 inversions.

Any idea of how to get the inversion's number?

[image]

```
public class MergesortAlgorithm{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {1, 5, 4, 8, 10, 2, 6, 9, 12, 11, 3, 7};

        System.out.println("Original array:");
        printArray(array);
        mergesort(array);

        System.out.println("\nOrdered array:");
        printArray(array);

        System.out.println("\nNumber of inversions: ?");
    }
    
    public static void mergesort (int[] array){
        // I got it to return the sorted array but I don't know how to get the number of inversions by now
        // I am having trouble locating them

        int inputLength = array.length;

        // If the array have less than 2 elementos, it will be ordered
        if (inputLength <2){
            return;
        }

        // It obtains the median of the array
        int midIndex = array.length / 2;

        // It creates the two empty sub-arrays
        int[] leftHalf = new int [midIndex]; // From 0 to mid
        int[] rightHalf = new int [inputLength - midIndex]; // From midIndex+1 to inputLength

        // It fills the leftHalf array from the original one
        for (int i = 0; i < midIndex; i++) {
            leftHalf[i] = array[i];
        }

        // It fills the rightHalf array from the original one
        for (int i = midIndex; i < array.length; i++) {
            rightHalf[i-midIndex] = array[i];   // "i-midIndex" because if i put "i" it starts in midIndex (in the new array)
        }        
        
        //It runs recursively until I have less than two elements on the arrays
        mergesort(leftHalf);
        mergesort(rightHalf);

        merge(array, leftHalf, rightHalf);
    }

    public static void merge (int[] array, int[] leftHalf, int[] rightHalf){

        int leftSize = leftHalf.length;
        int rightSize = rightHalf.length;

        int i = 0;  // "i" will run through the leftHalf
        int j = 0;  // "j" will run through the rightHalf
        int k = 0;  // "k" will run throught the merged array (final array)

        while (i < leftSize && j < rightSize) {  // It loops until we run out of elements in one of the two arrays
            if (leftHalf[i] <= rightHalf[j]) {  // If element in leftHalf is smaller, we put it on the merged array
                array[k] = leftHalf[i];
                i++;
            }
            else {  // Otherwise, we put the element of rightHalf on the merged array
                array[k] = rightHalf[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        // At this point, maybe one of the arrays could have "unrevised elements" because of an odd initial array (I think)
        // These two loops adds to the merged array the remaining items
        while (i < leftSize) {
            array[k] = leftHalf[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }

        while (j < rightSize) {
            array[k] = rightHalf[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }

    public static void printArray (int[] array) {
        System.out.printf("[ ");

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d ", array[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("]");
    }
}
```

I don't exactly know how to count the inversions, but, In which part of the could I established a counter and when increase it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an inversion count in both the `mergesort` and `merge` functions. Then, `mergesort` essentially returns the sum of the inversions from sorting both sides of the array and the number of inversions from merging.

The key here is that during the merging step, when you take an element from the right side, you essentially swap with every remaining element in the left side, so the number of inversions caused by that is the length of the left array minus the index of the current element reached in the left half.

Here is a modified version of your code that handles counting inversions:

```java
public static long mergesort(int[] array) {
    int inputLength = array.length;
    if (inputLength < 2)
        return 0;
    int midIndex = array.length / 2;
    int[] leftHalf = new int[midIndex];
    int[] rightHalf = new int[inputLength - midIndex];
    for (int i = 0; i < midIndex; i++) {
        leftHalf[i] = array[i];
    }
    for (int i = midIndex; i < array.length; i++) {
        rightHalf[i - midIndex] = array[i];
    }
    return mergesort(leftHalf) + mergesort(rightHalf) + merge(array, leftHalf, rightHalf);
}

public static long merge(int[] array, int[] leftHalf, int[] rightHalf) {
    int leftSize = leftHalf.length;
    int rightSize = rightHalf.length;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    long inversions = 0;
    while (i < leftSize && j < rightSize) {
        if (leftHalf[i] <= rightHalf[j]) {
            array[k] = leftHalf[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            array[k] = rightHalf[j];
            inversions += leftSize - i;
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i < leftSize) {
        array[k] = leftHalf[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < rightSize) {
        array[k] = rightHalf[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    return inversions;
}
```